# Heroku get logs of particular date

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli, heroku-api

I am using Heroku and now i need to see old logs by date.I googled but i didn't got any solution .any one know how to get logs of particular date ?

```
heroku logs --app myproject -n 200000
```

also tail command i tried

```
heroku logs --source app --tail
```

But above command only return max of 1500 lines even if i increase then i get only 2k lines.

Even i read document 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Answer (score 6):

The Heroku Logplex only stores the last 1500 log lines from your application dynos and add-ons. To store and search logs long-term, you'll need to stream your logs to an external service provider. Heroku provide many logging add-ons: https://elements.heroku.com/addons, or you can use your own service by setting up a log drain: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains.